# jquery tabs loading via ajax question

Tags: jquery, tabs, load

im using the standard jquery tabs 1.3.2 to load a list of bookmarks in each tab pane.

If a tab is clicked before the dom is ready the ajax page is loaded by itself. I don't want that to happen so how can I stop that behavior?

```
 <ul id="tool-tabs" class="tabs clearfix">
 <li class="ui-tabs-selected"><a href="#tools">Tools</a></li>
 <li><a id="bookmarks" href="/ajax.bookmarks.php">Bookmarks</a></li>
 <li><a id="favorites" href="/ajax.favorites.php">Favorites</a></li>
 </ul>
```

If i click Bookmarks as the page loads i get the the ajax page loaded to /mysite/ajax.bookmarks.php which i don't want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest thing is probably set the default style for the tab group to `display: none`, and then make it visible after the page is done loading.  You could also trying adding a `onClick="return false"` to disable them and then clear those with jQuery once they're ready for use.

Comment: thanks, its always the simplest things you overlook when you have a million things to finish.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //once dom get ready it happens
    $('#bookmarks').trigger('click');    
    $("#bookmarks").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });     
});
```

**Run your ajax codes and onsuccess of your ajax once again activate it.**

Answer (score 0):

try writing ur code inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are calling the tabs() function of jquery in the $(document).ready() method?
If this is the case you should not have a problem.